# External kbd not recognised on laptop running Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, laptop, keyboard

External kbd is not recognised when it is plugged into a USB port on my Acer 5810T laptop.
Laptop is running Win-7. I'm using a PS/2 to USB passive adapter.

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard has to support USB as well as PS/2 and a passive adaptor is just that, passive.  It does nothing except convert one pin format to another, it is up to the device being converted to realise that it should be "talking" in its other mode.

The devices that will work with that kind of adaptor, whether it is a keyboard or mouse, will generally come with those adaptors.  If it did not come with one then there is a good chance that the adaptor will do the sum total of absolutely nothing whatsoever.

Using an ancient PS/2 keyboard will not work with a PS/2 to USB adaptor.  Using a new USB keyboard with an inverted USB to PS/2 adaptor will only work if the keyboard is able to switch to PS/2 mode.